# How can we get JIRA rest authentication tokens in java class?

Tags: jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

We are developing JIRA report plugin in which we are accessing some fields using REST apis. For that we need authentication (i.e. username and password or authentication tokens) so how can we get it and from where.
we can't "get" a password from JIRA as it doesn't store them so how to get authentication tokens in rest calls

Note:We are using REST in one of our value generator class to get Custom fields .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a plugin for JIRA server (i.e. Java "version 2" plugin) then you should use appropriate Java API instead of REST calls.

If it's a connect plugin for JIRA cloud and you rely on Play Java Module for Atlassian Connect, then you should be able to sign request using AC.url method.